# Geometric Interpretation of $\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{k}{x^k}$

Tags: calculus, geometry

The series $\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{k}{2^k}$ can be solved by taking the derivative of the formula for the geometric series, multiplying by $x$, and then evaluating it at $x = \frac{1}{2}$.
$$\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{k}{2^k} = x \cdot \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{1}{1-x}\right] \left|_{x=\frac{1}{2}}\right. = 2$$

However, I am interested if this, like the geometric series, has a nifty geometric argument to go with it such as a $1$ by $2$ rectangle being divided in half infinitely many times for $\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{1}{2^k}$. Basically, what I am asking is if the series can be solved without relying on calculus and sticking to only geometry. If the series above has a geometric interpretation, I am also curious if $\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{k^n}{2^k}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ all have geometric interpretations too (note that the sum of each of these can be found by taking the derivative of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and multiplying by $x$ $n$ times and then plugging in $x=\frac{1}{2}$). Any ideas for where to even start looking for geometric arguments are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac k{2^k} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{2^k} \biggl( \sum_{m=1}^k 1 \biggr) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \biggl( \sum_{k=m}^\infty \frac1{2^k} \biggr).
$$
The $m=1$ term on the right-hand side represents rectangles that tile a larger rectangle of area $1$, as the OP described. But then the $m=2$ term represents rectangles that tile a larger rectangle of area $\frac12$, the $m=3$ term represents rectangles that tile a larger rectangle of area $\frac14$, and so on. And then all these larger rectangles tile an even larger rectangle of area $2$.

This scheme generalizes most straightforwardly to denominators that are "falling factorials", namely $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k(k-1)\cdots(k-(n-1))}{2^k}$ for fixed $n$ (the OP describes the $n=0$ case while the above paragraph describes the $n=1$ case). One can then convert these formulas into formulas for $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^n}{2^k}$ using [Stirling numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).